# Как запушить объект в массив в массиве в стейте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, redux

Ниже размещу типизацию для стейта Redux:

```js
export type TodoItem = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  order: number;
  content: string;
  isCompleted: boolean;
};

export type Boards = {
  title: string;
  id: string;
  order: number;
  items: TodoItem[] | [];
};

export type State = {
  boards: Boards[];
  settings?: any;
};
```

Я пытаюсь в слайсе запушить в массив items: TodoItem[] объект вот этой функцией:

```js
createTodo: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<[boardId: string, title: string, content: string]>,
    ) => {
      const findBoardIdx = (): number => {
        return state.boards.findIndex((board) => board.id === action.payload[0]);
      }; // Ищу борду для пуша туду.

      state.boards[findBoardIdx()].items.push({}); // Пушу здесь *условно* типизированный объект.
      // Но получаю данную ошибку: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    },
```

То есть, почему то, js теряется на этапе когда я ищу в массиве boards объект по id и push заместо ожидаемой логики, а-ля:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возвращает мне:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Ругается TS, что тип 'number' не совместим с объявленным типом.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы немного неверно типизировали `Boards`, поэтому TS не может понять какого типа у вас `items`. Поле items должно быть типизировано как `TodoItem[]`. Пустой массив тоже подойдет под этот тип.